# MintTo contract from web3 gives error - ERC721: transfer to non ERC721Receiver implementer

Tags: python, blockchain, ethereum, solidity, web3py

I am new to blockchain technology. I am trying to create a contract and then mint a token to contract using web3 python library.

I could create an contract. This is the link to contract in rinkeby

```
https://rinkeby.etherscan.io/address/0x466086b7002d6836c2e4ca05472ded70a7f5213b
```

Whenever I try to mint token to this. I am getting below error

```
web3.exceptions.ContractLogicError: execution reverted: ERC721: transfer to non ERC721Receiver implementer
```

This is my code to do the minting.

```
def test_with_setter_only_transfer():
    w3 = Web3(Web3.HTTPProvider("https://rinkeby.infura.io/v3/c0e4482bdf9e4f539692666cd56ef4e3"))
    w3.middleware_onion.inject(geth_poa_middleware, layer=0)
    
    address = '0x589a1532AAaE84e38345b58C11CF4697Ea89A866'
    abi = '[{"inputs":[{"internalType":"address","name":"_proxyRegistryAddress","type":"address"},{"internalType":"string","name":"url","type":"string"}],"stateMutability":"nonpayable","type":"constructor"},{"anonymous":false,"inputs":[{"indexed":true,"internalType":"address","name":"owner","type":"address"},{"indexed":true,"internalType":"address","name":"approved","type":"address"},{"indexed":true,"internalType":"uint256","name":"tokenId","type":"uint256"}],"name":"Approval","type":"event"},{"anonymous":false,"inputs":[{"indexed":true,"internalType":"address","name":"owner","type":"address"},{"indexed":true,"internalType":"address","name":"operator","type":"address"},{"indexed":false,"internalType":"bool","name":"approved","type":"bool"}],"name":"ApprovalForAll","type":"event"},{"anonymous":false,"inputs":[{"indexed":false,"internalType":"address","name":"userAddress","type":"address"},{"indexed":false,"internalType":"address payable","name":"relayerAddress","type":"address"},{"indexed":false,"internalType":"bytes","name":"functionSignature","type":"bytes"}],"name":"MetaTransactionExecuted","type":"event"},{"anonymous":false,"inputs":[{"indexed":true,"internalType":"address","name":"previousOwner","type":"address"},{"indexed":true,"internalType":"address","name":"newOwner","type":"address"}],"name":"OwnershipTransferred","type":"event"},{"anonymous":false,"inputs":[{"indexed":true,"internalType":"address","name":"from","type":"address"},{"indexed":true,"internalType":"address","name":"to","type":"address"},{"indexed":true,"internalType":"uint256","name":"tokenId","type":"uint256"}],"name":"Transfer","type":"event"},{"inputs":[],"name":"ERC712_VERSION","outputs":[{"internalType":"string","name":"","type":"string"}],"stateMutability":"view","type":"function"},{"inputs":[{"internalType":"address","name":"to","type":"address"},{"internalType":"uint256","name":"tokenId","type":"uint256"}],"name":"approve","outputs":[],"stateMutability":"nonpayable","type":"function"},{"inputs":[{"internalType":"address","name":"owner","type":"address"}],"name":"balanceOf","outputs":[{"internalType":"uint256","name":"","type":"uint256"}],"stateMutability":"view","type":"function"},{"inputs":[],"name":"baseTokenURI","outputs":[{"internalType":"string","name":"","type":"string"}],"stateMutability":"view","type":"function"},{"inputs":[{"internalType":"address","name":"userAddress","type":"address"},{"internalType":"bytes","name":"functionSignature","type":"bytes"},{"internalType":"bytes32","name":"sigR","type":"bytes32"},{"internalType":"bytes32","name":"sigS","type":"bytes32"},{"internalType":"uint8","name":"sigV","type":"uint8"}],"name":"executeMetaTransaction","outputs":[{"internalType":"bytes","name":"","type":"bytes"}],"stateMutability":"payable","type":"function"},{"inputs":[{"internalType":"uint256","name":"tokenId","type":"uint256"}],"name":"getApproved","outputs":[{"internalType":"address","name":"","type":"address"}],"stateMutability":"view","type":"function"},{"inputs":[],"name":"getChainId","outputs":[{"internalType":"uint256","name":"","type":"uint256"}],"stateMutability":"view","type":"function"},{"inputs":[],"name":"getDomainSeperator","outputs":[{"internalType":"bytes32","name":"","type":"bytes32"}],"stateMutability":"view","type":"function"},{"inputs":[{"internalType":"address","name":"user","type":"address"}],"name":"getNonce","outputs":[{"internalType":"uint256","name":"nonce","type":"uint256"}],"stateMutability":"view","type":"function"},{"inputs":[{"internalType":"address","name":"owner","type":"address"},{"internalType":"address","name":"operator","type":"address"}],"name":"isApprovedForAll","outputs":[{"internalType":"bool","name":"","type":"bool"}],"stateMutability":"view","type":"function"},{"inputs":[{"internalType":"address","name":"_to","type":"address"}],"name":"mintTo","outputs":[],"stateMutability":"nonpayable","type":"function"},{"inputs":[],"name":"name","outputs":[{"internalType":"string","name":"","type":"string"}],"stateMutability":"view","type":"function"},{"inputs":[],"name":"owner","outputs":[{"internalType":"address","name":"","type":"address"}],"stateMutability":"view","type":"function"},{"inputs":[{"internalType":"uint256","name":"tokenId","type":"uint256"}],"name":"ownerOf","outputs":[{"internalType":"address","name":"","type":"address"}],"stateMutability":"view","type":"function"},{"inputs":[],"name":"renounceOwnership","outputs":[],"stateMutability":"nonpayable","type":"function"},{"inputs":[{"internalType":"address","name":"from","type":"address"},{"internalType":"address","name":"to","type":"address"},{"internalType":"uint256","name":"tokenId","type":"uint256"}],"name":"safeTransferFrom","outputs":[],"stateMutability":"nonpayable","type":"function"},{"inputs":[{"internalType":"address","name":"from","type":"address"},{"internalType":"address","name":"to","type":"address"},{"internalType":"uint256","name":"tokenId","type":"uint256"},{"internalType":"bytes","name":"_data","type":"bytes"}],"name":"safeTransferFrom","outputs":[],"stateMutability":"nonpayable","type":"function"},{"inputs":[{"internalType":"address","name":"operator","type":"address"},{"internalType":"bool","name":"approved","type":"bool"}],"name":"setApprovalForAll","outputs":[],"stateMutability":"nonpayable","type":"function"},{"inputs":[{"internalType":"string","name":"counter","type":"string"}],"name":"setCounter","outputs":[],"stateMutability":"nonpayable","type":"function"},{"inputs":[{"internalType":"bytes4","name":"interfaceId","type":"bytes4"}],"name":"supportsInterface","outputs":[{"internalType":"bool","name":"","type":"bool"}],"stateMutability":"view","type":"function"},{"inputs":[],"name":"symbol","outputs":[{"internalType":"string","name":"","type":"string"}],"stateMutability":"view","type":"function"},{"inputs":[{"internalType":"uint256","name":"_tokenId","type":"uint256"}],"name":"tokenURI","outputs":[{"internalType":"string","name":"","type":"string"}],"stateMutability":"view","type":"function"},{"inputs":[],"name":"totalSupply","outputs":[{"internalType":"uint256","name":"","type":"uint256"}],"stateMutability":"view","type":"function"},{"inputs":[{"internalType":"address","name":"from","type":"address"},{"internalType":"address","name":"to","type":"address"},{"internalType":"uint256","name":"tokenId","type":"uint256"}],"name":"transferFrom","outputs":[],"stateMutability":"nonpayable","type":"function"},{"inputs":[{"internalType":"address","name":"newOwner","type":"address"}],"name":"transferOwnership","outputs":[],"stateMutability":"nonpayable","type":"function"}]'

    
    w3.eth.defaultAccount = address

    private_key = "905a362c6d17d5b87f7941fa73a3bb08bd7473e226b760437269b017xxxxxxx"


    contract = w3.eth.contract(
        address='0x466086b7002d6836c2E4Ca05472deD70A7f5213b',
        abi=abi,
    )

    print('Base Token URI: {}'.format(contract.functions.baseTokenURI().call()))

    token_id = contract.functions.totalSupply().call()
    print('Token ID: {}'.format(token_id))

    print('Token URI: {}'.format(contract.functions.tokenURI(token_id).call()))

    print(f'block number after deploying : {w3.eth.blockNumber}')

    # Change the value of counter and transact

    # # update the greeting
    tx_hash = contract.functions.mintTo(Web3.toChecksumAddress('0x466086b7002d6836c2E4Ca05472deD70A7f5213b')).buildTransaction()
    tx_hash.update({'gas': 20000000})
    tx_hash.update({'nonce': w3.eth.getTransactionCount(address)})
    signed_tx = w3.eth.account.sign_transaction(tx_hash, private_key)

    txn_hash = w3.eth.send_raw_transaction(signed_tx.rawTransaction)

    # # Wait for transaction to be mined...
    rec = w3.eth.waitForTransactionReceipt(txn_hash)

    print(rec)
```

This is the contract which I have created

```
pragma solidity ^0.8.0;

import "./ERC721Tradable.sol";
import "@openzeppelin/contracts/access/Ownable.sol";

/**
 * @title Creature
 * Creature - a contract for my non-fungible creatures.
 */
contract Creature is ERC721Tradable {

  string _baseURL;

  constructor(address _proxyRegistryAddress, string memory url) ERC721Tradable("Creature", "OSC", _proxyRegistryAddress) {
      _baseURL = url ;
   }

  function baseTokenURI() public override view returns (string memory) {
    return _baseURL;
  }
}
```

This is the ERC721Tradable file

```
// SPDX-License-Identifier: MIT

pragma solidity ^0.8.0;

import "@openzeppelin/contracts/token/ERC721/ERC721.sol";
import "@openzeppelin/contracts/access/Ownable.sol";
import "@openzeppelin/contracts/utils/Counters.sol";
import "@openzeppelin/contracts/utils/Strings.sol";
import "@openzeppelin/contracts/utils/math/SafeMath.sol";

import "./ContentMixin.sol";
import "./NativeMetaTransaction.sol";

contract OwnableDelegateProxy {}

/**
 * Used to delegate ownership of a contract to another address, to save on unneeded transactions to approve contract use for users
 */
contract ProxyRegistry {
    mapping(address => OwnableDelegateProxy) public proxies;
}

/**
 * @title ERC721Tradable
 * ERC721Tradable - ERC721 contract that whitelists a trading address, and has minting functionality.
 */
abstract contract ERC721Tradable is ERC721, ContextMixin, NativeMetaTransaction, Ownable {
    using SafeMath for uint256;
    using Counters for Counters.Counter;

    Counters.Counter private _nextTokenId;
    address proxyRegistryAddress;

    constructor(
        string memory _name,
        string memory _symbol,
        address _proxyRegistryAddress
    ) ERC721(_name, _symbol) {
        proxyRegistryAddress = _proxyRegistryAddress;
        // nextTokenId is initialized to 1, since starting at 0 leads to higher gas cost for the first minter
        _nextTokenId.increment();
        _initializeEIP712(_name);
    }

    /**
     * @dev Mints a token to an address with a tokenURI.
     * @param _to address of the future owner of the token
     */
    function mintTo(address _to) public onlyOwner {
        uint256 currentTokenId = _nextTokenId.current();
        _nextTokenId.increment();
        _safeMint(_to, currentTokenId);
    }

    /**
        @dev Returns the total tokens minted so far.
        1 is always subtracted from the Counter since it tracks the next available tokenId.
     */
    function totalSupply() public view returns (uint256) {
        return _nextTokenId.current() - 1;
    }

    function baseTokenURI() virtual public view returns (string memory);

    function tokenURI(uint256 _tokenId) override public view returns (string memory) {
        return string(abi.encodePacked(baseTokenURI(), Strings.toString(_tokenId)));
    }

    /**
     * Override isApprovedForAll to whitelist user's OpenSea proxy accounts to enable gas-less listings.
     */
    function isApprovedForAll(address owner, address operator)
        override
        public
        view
        returns (bool)
    {
        // Whitelist OpenSea proxy contract for easy trading.
        ProxyRegistry proxyRegistry = ProxyRegistry(proxyRegistryAddress);
        if (address(proxyRegistry.proxies(owner)) == operator) {
            return true;
        }

        return super.isApprovedForAll(owner, operator);
    }

    /**
     * This is used instead of msg.sender as transactions won't be sent by the original token owner, but by OpenSea.
     */
    function _msgSender()
        internal
        override
        view
        returns (address sender)
    {
        return ContextMixin.msgSender();
    }
}
```

Comment: I dont know how do you make the contract, but the given error let me think that either the address of the receiver is invalid or the contract don't have [IERC721Receiver](https://docs.openzeppelin.com/contracts/4.x/api/token/erc721#IERC721Receiver) implemented.

Comment: Address I have given the link in the question. I can see that. How to implement IERC721Receiver? I have updated the question with contract

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think first error is when you build a transaction, you need to pass an object:

```
 tx_hash = contract.functions.mintTo(Web3.toChecksumAddress('0x466086b7002d6836c2E4Ca05472deD70A7f5213b')).buildTransaction({

        "chainId": chain_id,
        "gasPrice": w3.eth.gas_price,
        "from": whatever_address,
        "nonce": nonce_value,
})
```

chain Ids

```
NETWORK_CHAIN_IDS = {
  1: "Ethereum Main Network",
  3: "Ropsten Test Network",
  4: "Rinkeby Test Network",
  5: "Goerli Test Network",
  42: "Kovan Test Network",
  56: "Binance Smart Chain",
  1337: "Ganache",
};
```

Comment: how to get chain id?

Comment: @NikeshKedlaya paste it to the answer

Comment: Updated the transaction like you mentioned. Still the same error!

Comment: @NikeshKedlaya  Now please share the code with mint function and transfer function

Comment: Updated my question with ERC271Tradable file

Comment: @NikeshKedlaya pls share ERC721Receiver and interface for ERC721Receiver

Comment: It should be there in openzeppelin/contracts/token/ERC721/ERC721.sol. I have not written any such files. Do i have to write those? If yes can you pls provide me some example contract for the same?

Comment: @NikeshKedlaya you might achieve it by just reading a bit more the [implementation](https://docs.openzeppelin.com/contracts/4.x/erc721) of the erc721 (v4) on the doc along a simple  [example](https://soliditydeveloper.com/erc-721) 

Comment: Working! Thanks a lot